# How to detect if a command spawed from Rust resulted in Segmentation Fault?

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault

I am working to build a wrapper to test an application that occasionally results in a Segmentation Fault.

```
use std::io::{Write};
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {

  let input_name = "Saqib Ali";
  let input_email = "saqib@test.com"
  let input_serial_numer = "SN103213112"
  let register_app = Command::new("register_drive").stdin(Stdio::piped()).spawn().unwrap();
  write!(register_app.stdin.unwrap(), "{}", input_name).unwrap();

}
```

How do I detect if a program resulted in Segmentation Fault when a `input_name` was sent to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wait for the process to finish and use the Unix-specific `ExitStatusExt` trait to extract the signal code out of the exit status and the `libc` crate to identify the signal as `SIGSEGV`:

```
use std::os::unix::process::ExitStatusExt;

let input_name = "Saqib Ali";
let mut register_app = Command::new("register_drive")
    .stdin(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()
    .unwrap();
write!(register_app.stdin.as_mut().unwrap(), "{}", input_name).unwrap();
let status = register_app.wait().unwrap();
match status.signal() {
    Some(signal) if signal == libc::SIGSEGV => {
        println!("the process resulted in segmentation fault");
    }
    _ => println!("the process resulted in {:?}", status),
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=179d70bedbef09e54020c04d52c39a2b)

Note that you might want to use `writeln!()` to write to the program's stdin, otherwise the line with the input name won't be terminated and might get merged with subsequent input.

Comment: When I compile using rustc I get the following. Please advise:
  |     ^^^^ maybe a missing crate `libc`?

Comment: @SaqibAli Yes, you need to add `libc` to `Cargo.toml`. (I neglected to mention it because it's automatically included in the playground.)